# How can I add an async middleware to a router route

Tags: javascript, express

I have an expresss router, and I'm configuring some routes for it, I pass a validator for the data and a handler, but the validator has to work with some promises so I need to place an await, the code that I wrote looks like this:

```
constructor() {
    this.router = express.Router();
    this.router.use(express.json());
    this.router.use(express.text({ type: ['text/plain', 'text/html'] }));
  }

  async addCreateTaskRoute(validator, handler) {
    if (!handler) {
      throw Error('cannot add empty handler');
    }

    this.router.post('/tasks', await validator, handler);

    return this;
  }
```

Does this solution look alright to you? Are there any other options?
The project that this is included in is a middleware, and the validator and handlers come from other modules and the type of them is express RequestHandler

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Your `validator` should call `next()` asynchronously after successful validation, this will then invoke the next middleware, which is `handler`. After unsuccessful validation, an error is returned and `next()` is not called so that no further middlewares are processed.

```js
async function validator(req, res, next) {
  var valid = await validationResult(...);
  if (valid) next();
  else res.status(400).end("Error message");
}
this.router.post("/tasks", validator, handler);
```